# Why does "git remote add" create a "fetch" refspec but not a "push" refspec?

Tags: git

According to the documentation for git config, the following two items are supported:

```
remote.<name>.fetch
    The default set of "refspec" for git-fetch(1). See git-fetch(1).

remote.<name>.push
    The default set of "refspec" for git-push(1). See git-push(1).
```

However, when I issue

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```

I see that only the fetch refspec is added. Why is "push" treated second class here? What is the rationale?

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems like it could be documented better, it probably has something to do with this:

> **`push.default`**
>
> Defines the action `git push` should take if no refspec is given on the command line, no refspec is configured in the remote, and no refspec is implied by any of the options given on the command line.
>
> Possible values are:
>
> - `nothing` – do not push anything.
> - `matching` – push all matching branches. All branches having the same name in both ends are considered to be matching. This is the default.
> - `tracking` – push the current branch to its upstream branch.
> - `current` – push the current branch to a branch of the same name.

The default push refspec(s) is(are) controlled by the `push.default` setting, so, unless you want something other than the default for the setting you have, there’s no need for a per-remote push refspec. However, if you want one remote to work in one way and another remote to work differently, you can specify the details with per-remote push refspecs.